# Insert data into form after load url with WebView

Tags: android, webview

after i load the url with WebView, can i insert into form page some data in auto?

i try with:

```
 @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                String user="pippo";
                String pwd="secret";
                view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('j_username').value = '"+user+"';document.getElementById('j_password').value='"+pwd+"';");
            }
```

But not work..

The HTML source is:

```
<html>

....
    <form action="/.../" method="post">

                <table align="center">
                <tr>
                <td>
                <table>
                <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input name="j_username" type="text" tabindex="1"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input name="j_password" type="password" tabindex="2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login" tabindex="3"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                        <!--</form>-->
                        </form>

...
<\html>
```

Comment: Where are you specifying the id j_username in the two forms? I see only the name, type and tabindex properties..

Comment: ops yes..i must use document.getElementByName ?

Comment: getElementByName() doesn't exist, you have to use getElementsByName that will return a collection and you have to get the element in position [0] for username and element in position [1] for password. This will work only if those two names properties are the first two in the html page that you load. I highly recommend you to use id properties if you can change html, they are more precise and will not change if html code is added..

Comment: @Fondesa so if i try with: javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0].value = '"+user+"';document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[1].value ='"+pwd+"';" and is only this form it work?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get your data into all `Strings`  and forward them to the class where you want like this :

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    private Context ctx;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
@JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html) throws JSONException {
        System.out.println(html);
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(html);
        String sts = jsonResponse.getString("status");
        if (sts.equals("success")) {
            message = jsonResponse.getString("msg");
            approved_status = jsonResponse.getString("approved");
            jsonObj = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("data");
            user_email = jsonObj.getString("user_email");
            phone_no = jsonObj.getString("phone_no");
            user_gender = jsonObj.getString("gender");
            first_name = jsonObj.getString("first_name");
            last_name = jsonObj.getString("last_name");
            ids = jsonObj.getString("id");
            id = Integer.parseInt(ids);
}
}
```

And if your final page is in `HTML` then use this code:

```
@Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            wb.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML"
                    + "(document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML);");
        }
```

Comment: Is it HTML page from where you're getting data?